# Is it possible to hide curve handles behind other objects?

Tags: bezier-curves, visibility

I'm working on a scene with a lot of curves and I was wondering if it's possible to hide the curve handles behind other objects in the scene? so just obscuring the curve handles behind other objects. You can see in the GIF how all these handles can be quite annoying and witch handles I want to be obscured by the basic face object.
I hope this is possible, thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: No, i don't think that is possible

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not currently possible.

What you could do is separate them into more objects and leave the ones that you are not currently working on in object mode or even hide them. You can also hide splines of the same object or parts of them in edit mode by selecting them and hitting <kbd>h</kbd>(<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to unhide all or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to hide everything except selection)

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible, but here's a workaround:

Convert the curves to vertices (remove the curve's geometry first.) Use the skin modifier to give them thickness again. Then do your layout. Then convert them back to curves and setup the geometry again.